# How to configure settings to deploy my existing Django project to PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, pythonanywhere, django-wsgi

I am having a hard time deploying my finished Django project to PythonAnywhere. It looks like it has to do with my Django secret key, which I never seem to handle correctly. The secret key is exposed in settings.py, which I know is not advised, but whenever I put it into an environment variable PythonAnywhere throws an error that it can't find it. Can anyone help me configure my settings.py + "pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py" file to correctly deploy my application?

Github link to project: https://github.com/mollycg/django-portfolio

PythonAnywhere error log:

```
Error running WSGI application
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873: decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873:   File "/var/www/mollycg_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873:     application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-12-03 22:32:51,873:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:     self._setup(name)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,874:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:   File "./magic_django/settings.py", line 21, in <module>
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:     SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:     return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:     return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,875:   File "/home/mollycg/.virtualenvs/mgdp-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 68, in get
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876:     raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876: ***************************************************
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-12-03 22:32:51,876: ***************************************************
```

The error log also references a package I tried to use for the SECRET_KEY, python-decouple, which I have since stopped using in settings.py. If I need to use it, that works too, but it wasn't working when I tried earlier.

PythonAnywhere WSGI file:

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.expanduser('~/mollycg/django-portfolio')
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'magic_django.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: You need to provide that variable in some way. python-decouple can use ini and .env files, so you can have a look at using one of those to provide the variable to your web app.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you for the input.